# identifier calcHist() is undefined in OpenCV in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to calculate histogram of an Image using OpenCV in C++, but I get this error:

```
error: identifier calcHist() is undefined
```

in OpenCV in C++ in Visual Studio 2013

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat original=imread("my.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    namedWindow("Original Image",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Original Image",original);
    waitKey(5000);  
    calcHist();
}
```

But Visual Studio Identifies `cvCalcHist()` function, unfortunately all the reference materials I have used `calcHist()` function and I am comfortable with it.

Comment: Include also imgproc

Comment: Thank You.That exactly solved my problem.

Comment: just include `#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>` which includes all, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#calchist) is in Image Processing (`imgproc`) module, you should include it like:

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
```

Note that OpenCV provides also a an *include all* header that includes all the modules for you (except for `nonfree` module):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call calcHist() but give no parameters. None of the overloads for the calcHist function have all default values, so you need pass more arguments if you want it work.

See the OpenCV documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) for C++ example.